# Tornado proxy whith nginx and subpaths

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, proxy, tornado

I'd like to redirect requests from my www.mydomain.com/subdirectory to a respective Tornado server like this:

```
www.example.com/app1 -> http://10.0.0.5:8082;
www.example.com/app2 -> http://10.0.0.6:8082;
www.example.com/app3 -> http://10.0.0.7:8082;
```

I have this nginx config:

```
location ^~ /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.5:8082/;
    }

location ^~ /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.6:8082/;
    }

location ^~ /app3 {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.7:8082/;
    }
```

My Tornado app:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("main.html")

class HomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("home.html")

class UserHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        self.render("user.html")

class UserStatusHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        self.render("user_status.html")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/home", HomeHandler),
        (r"/user/([0-9]*)", UserHandler),
        (r"/user/([0-9]*)/status", UserStatusHandler),
        '''
        my app have a lot of other pages with subpaths
        '''
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8082)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

So, when a hit:

```
http://www.example.com/app1 -> it works, main.html is rendered
http://www.example.com/app1/ -> Tornado throws an warning: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET // (10.0.0.5) 0.41ms
http://www.example.com/app1/home -> Tornado throws an warning: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET //home (10.0.0.5) 0.41ms
http://www.example.com/app1/home/ -> Tornado throws an warning: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET //home/ (10.0.0.5) 0.41ms
http://www.example.com/app1/user/1 -> Tornado throws an warning: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET //user/1 (10.0.0.5) 0.41ms
http://www.example.com/app1/user/1/status -> Tornado throws an warning: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET //user/1/status (10.0.0.5) 0.41ms
```

That extra / on url is causing the error

So please, can anybody help me?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136484/different-behavour-of-location-and-proxy-pass-on-nginx-x-accel-redirect/42136892#42136892)

Comment: So nice!
It works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the / on my location solved the problem.
Thanks Richard Smith.