# Node app receives also the location name of nginx configuration

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have the following node.js/express app

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("this is the main route")
})

app.get('/proveedor', function(req, res) {
    res.send("proveedor route")
})

app.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log("running node server")
})
```

And a configuration file of nginx like this

```
location /proveedor {
   proxy_pass   http://localhost:3001;


   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

When I test it and go to `http://my.domain.com/proveedor` the node.js app receives the request as `http://localhost:3001/proveedor` so the response is "proveedor route".

My question is if there is a way to make that at every call at `http://my.domain.com/proveedor` goes to node.js app not like `http://localhost:3001/proveedor` but `http://localhost:3001/` to get the answer "this is the main route".

Then, if I want to call to `http://localhost:3001/proveedor` I will call to `http://my.domain.com/proveedor/proveedor`.

Comment: What you got there looks correct to me. I will try `location /proveedor/` and `proxy_pass    http://localhost:3001/` thou. Not sure if the `/` helps or not. See the guide "https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/" how they always got `/` included at the end. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hi Samuel, I tried the way you suggest. But when I call to server it throws me a `cannot Get http://my.domain//proveedor/`. It seems it appends two times "//", and it's logic.

Comment: Silly question here before I give up. Did you have the `;` at the end of `proxy pass`? You probably do because otherwise it would have fail to start or something.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136484/different-behavour-of-location-and-proxy-pass-on-nginx-x-accel-redirect/42136892#42136892) (but delete the `internal;` statements)